# only sum with matching criteria

Tags: filter, conditional-statements, sum

[image]

I want to sum up all the apples and bananas.

```
=SUM(D1:D4,C1:C4=A1:A4)
```

This is returning 19 for apple and 19 for banana instead of 16,3.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

=SUMIFS(D1:D4,C1:C4=A1:A4)